# Failed to generate sqlite database in GTKpod

Tags: 11.10, ipod

I am able to connect my iPod Nano 5th generation(Black color + video camera) to GTKopd and transfer mp3 files to it. Upon trying to save those files so that I can eject my iPod the error message 'Failed to generate sqlite database' usually pops up. It's like GTKpod doesn't support 5th generation Nano iPod though. Now, is there any way(s) to get these mp3 files save to my iPod in Oneiric Ocelot?

I was able to use the File Manager to connect and transfer many of the songs to the Ipod but, the mp3 files never played for some reasons unknown to me.

Comment: Can browse the ipod via a file manager?

Comment: That does it! And, it allows me to add songs directly from the folder.

Comment: I added an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use your file manager to transfer the files.

If you have some files that are already on the player, take a look at how their tags are formatted, and see if you can match it up with the files you are transferring now.

Comment: One thing is that they were transferred very well but never played. So, I am waiting for more ideas before awarding the point.

Comment: @all4naija - you should add that comment to the question.  Also you should clarify how you obtained the mp3 files - most mp3 players need a correctly formatted ID tag to play with.

Comment: I meant to +1 fossfreedom's comment only :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work but try syncing with banshee or rhythmbox. It probably won't make a difference as they both use the same libimobiledevice / libgpod but you might get lucky. :P

Comment: I have tried both of them - they hardly did anything,even, less effective when compared to GTKpod! Thanks,anyway.